# Redirect loop after oauth using the mirror api with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm trying to implement the mirror api into a wordpress site, but after I log in and authenticate, the site tries to load for about 30 seconds, then fails saying that there was a redirect loop.

The way I am implementing the mirror api is by creating a template with all the php needed for oauth and whatnot, then using builder for the layout, content, etc. I think it might be a problem with wordpress, but I don't want to give up hope just yet.

Thank you for your help

Edit: Here is the code that I am using in my template for the wordpress page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Glass
*/

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/glass/config.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/glass/mirror-client.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/glass/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/glass/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_MirrorService.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/glass/util.php';

$client = get_google_api_client();
$message= "";
$subscriptionId;
if(isset($_GET['message']))
    $message = $_GET['message'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || get_credentials($_SESSION['userid']) == null) {
    header('Location: ' . $base_url . '/oauth2callback.php');
    exit;
} else {
    $client->setAccessToken(get_credentials($_SESSION['userid']));
}

// A glass service for interacting with the Mirror API
$mirror_service = new Google_MirrorService($client);

$subscriptions = $mirror_service->subscriptions->listSubscriptions();
$timeline_subscription_exists = false;
foreach ($subscriptions->getItems() as $subscription) {
    if ($subscription->getId() == 'timeline') {
        $timeline_subscription_exists = true;
        $subscriptionId = $subscription->getId();
    }
}
switch ($_GET['operation']){
    case 'createSubscription':
    $message = subscribe_to_notifications($mirror_service, "timeline",
        $_SESSION['userid'], "https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?    url=".$base_url."/notify.php");

        //Refresh Page
    $mHeader = 'Location: ' . $base_url;
    if($message != "")
        $mHeader = $mHeader . '?message='.$message;
    header($mHeader);   exit;
    break;

    case 'deleteSubscription':
    $message = $mirror_service->subscriptions->delete($subscriptionId);

        //Refresh Page
    $mHeader = 'Location: ' . $base_url;
    if($message != "")
        $mHeader = $mHeader . '?message='.$message;
    header($mHeader);
    exit;
    break;

    case 'refreshCard':
    createControlCard($client);
    header('Location: ' . $base_url);
    exit;
    break;

    case 'refreshInfo':
    generateInfoCards($client);
    header('Location: ' . $base_url);
    exit;
    break;
}


get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="widecolumn">
    <div id="main">



    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post some code illustrating how you are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be sure without seeing the exact code you're using, but it sounds like what might be happening is the following:

1. A person arrives on your page (without authentication) and you send them to Google's page to do so.
2. They authenticate there. After authenticating, they're redirected back to your page (which is the one you set as the OAuth redirect).
3. Back at your page, you don't detect that they're authenticated. So you send them back to Google.
4. Google detects they're already authenticated, so they helpfully redirect them back to your page (which is the one you set as the OAuth redirect).
5. GOTO 3

It sounds like the problem you're encountering is that you never correctly handle when they are authenticated - either because the page Google is redirecting them to doesn't know how to handle this, or because you're checking incorrectly. Without seeing your code, it is difficult to tell.

Additionally, you may want to investigate using the [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) (possibly with the server-side flow) to handle the authentication, since it does not require redirects after authentication completes, but instead has JavaScript callbacks.

**Update**: Since you're basing your work on the Quckstart, make sure that you have set your Redirect URL correctly, as indicated in steps 5 and 6 [of the Quickstart directions](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/php). You may also want to hit these URLs directly to make sure the correct page is being called. (And make sure it is the correct script, not just any script).

You may also want to add some debugging to the oauth2callback.php to determine what it is being called with and from where the calls are coming (the Referrer). It sounds like it is caught in a loop, somehow, where the oauth2callback is never called with the "code" parameter, so it continuously loops around the earlier stages of the auth flow.

Comment: I'm following the php quickstart example.
I just posted the code back in the main post. Also, I use this on my other site and it works just fine. that is why I'm confused.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more things to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem is WordPress. WordPress disables the use of the global variable '_SESSION', which the quick start project uses a lot. I am currently working on ways around this. If anyone has any suggestions, please message me or put an edit under this.

The loop is caused by oauth2callback not being able to set code to _SESSION, and when the website redirects back to the base, the base redirects because there is no userid .

Thank You for helping me.